# Metasearch like library in Play Framework

Tags: search, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

When I want to offer basic searching capabilities in a web application in Rails, I install Metasearch or Ransack and am happy with it. They are simple, flexible and save me time.

Now I'm developing a Java / Play Framework 2.0 application, and I would like to let my users filter some tables. Is there a plugin / best practice to do this using EBean? If we migrate to JPA, is there some "equivalent" to Metasearch (that is not *simple* to use?).

Regards,

Kurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such equivalent in Play, anyway searching is easy with Ebean API. Don't see reason for using any overlay for this task.